# run code when DOM of embded vendor component updates

Tags: angular

I am using a vendor component in `MyComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<vendor-component></vendor-component>`
})

export class MyComponent {
  constructor() { }

}
```

I want to do some jQuery stuff every time after the DOM of my embeded vendor component updates.

How can I do that ?
Is there a hook on `ViewChild` that could do it ?

Comment: `ngDoCheck` or `ngAfterViewCheck` on the child maybe

Answer (score 0):

> I want to do some jQuery stuff every time after the DOM of my embeded vendor component updates.

That **does not sound like a good idea, as you are not supposed to mess with the DOM directly**.Actualy, even built-in directives do not touch the DOM directly, they use the [`RootRenderer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/RootRenderer-class.html)/[`Renderer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html) API.

Maybe forking your vendor component and changing the way it behaves would be a better solution.

But, if you don't want to alter vendor's code, you can try to run your function in the `AfterViewChecked` hook :

```js
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  constructor() { }
  ngAfterViewChecked(){
    // do stuff
  }
}
```